# I need to COUNT the number of times "LOI-" occurs in a range if the date in a neighboring column for that row falls within a specified range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I need to COUNT the number of times "LOI-" occur in a range if the date in a neighboring column for that row falls within a specified range. I also want to save the new sum as a variable.  This is what I am trying:

```vb
NumACXV = Application.CountIfs(.Range("P2:W" & last), _
                  .Range("P2:W" & last), "* LOI- *", _
                  .Range("K2:K" & last), ">12/31/2013", _
                  .Range("K2:K" & last), "<8/1/2015")
```

Comment: And what happens when you try that?

Comment: Do you need to have worksheetFunction? `application.worksheetfunction.countifS` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams the result is #VALUE!

Comment: @PGSystemTester I had tried using only .Worsheetfuntion and I got an error, i cant remember which but i can tried your suggestion. ~UPDATE~ I get the error "Type Mismatch"

Comment: @ZMichelson you should close this question, or accept an answer.

Comment: @PGSystemTester im noob status and dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the SumIfs formula whos syntax is Range 1, Range 2, Range 2 Criteria

CountIfs seems to be using Range 1, Range 1 Criteria, Range 2, Range 2 Criteria

the working code is :
`NumACXV = Application.CountIfs(.Range("P2:P" & last), "<>", .Range("P2:P" & last), "*LOI-*", .Range("K2:K" & last), ">12/31/2013", .Range("K2:K" & last), "<8/1/2015")`

Answer (score 0):

The other answer does identify the issue with your formula where the countifs basically just counts multiple ranges with same array lengths (they don't have to be lined up -- but probabaly a good idea).

A direct solution can be used below and tested [on this file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9gvAc7Twd8aQkx9RCgw?e=WUXUtJ).

```
Sub testCountifS()

Dim yourCountRange As Range, dateRng As Range

Set yourCountRange = Intersect(Range("P2:P999999"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange) 'or whatever
Set dateRng = Intersect(yourCountRange.EntireRow, Range("K:K")) 'ensures rows match

NumACXV = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(yourCountRange, "*LOI-*", _
    dateRng, ">" & "12/31/2013", _
    dateRng, "<" & "8/1/2015")

MsgBox NumACXV
End Sub
```

**Arrays?**
For anyone who shared my curiosity thate there might be some performance improvements available using an array instead of Excel's CountIfs.... WRONG. CountIf's performed far faster than my basic array evaluation. I tested a million rows.