# COUNT the number of times “LOI-” occurs in a range of multiple columns if the date in a single column for that row falls within a specified range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I need to COUNT the number of times "LOI-" occur in a range of multiple columns if the date in a single column for that row falls within a specified range. I also want to save the new sum as a variable. This is what I am trying:

```vb
NumTest = Application.CountIfs(.Range("P2:II" & last), "*LOI-*",_
                               .Range("K2:K" & last), ">12/31/2013",_  
                               .Range("K2:K" & last), "<8/1/2015")`
```

Comment: Resulting value is #VALUE!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216168/old-question-criteria-updated-in-new-question/64216735#64216735

Comment: Do not use COUNTIFS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216168/old-question-criteria-updated-in-new-question

Comment: Load the ranges into variant arrays.  Loop the date range, if it falls in the desired dates then loop that "row" in the variant array and count.

Comment: You cannot have one range with multiple columns and another with singular with countifs.  You would need to have them the same size and shape.  so for what you want Countifs will not work.  You can work around it with Sumproduct, but I would recommend scrapping the worksheetfunction and use vba commands.

Comment: @ScottCraner a bit out of my depth, trying to read up on arrays now

Comment: @ScottCraner were just moving further and further out of my depth lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This custom function will do it in either excel or within your vba Routine. You can see it being used [in this file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9gvAcsSiMk_b6jWs37A?e=dfGR9S), but you'll need to download your own copy.

```
Function WeirdCountif(rangeOfTextToSearch As Range, text2Search As String, listofDates As Range, highestDate As Long, lowestDate As Long) As Long

Dim dRange As Range, aRange As Range

For Each dRange In listofDates.Cells
    If dRange.Value <= highestDate And dRange.Value >= lowestDate Then
        For Each aRange In Intersect(dRange.EntireRow, rangeOfTextToSearch).Cells
            If InStr(1, aRange.Value, text2Search, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                WeirdCountif = WeirdCountif + 1
            End If
        Next aRange
    End If
Next dRange


End Function
```

Comment: how do i download the file?

Comment: @ZMichelson I made the file smaller, should be able to download.

Comment: when im entering the highest date and lowest, do i need to enter as a hard coded date or cell reference?

Comment: How would it look in an Excel VBA Macro? this is what i am trying: NumTest = PERSONAL.XLSB!.WeirdCountif(.Range("P2:II100000"),"LOI-",.Range("K2:K100000"),"8/1/2015" ,"12/31/2013)

Comment: @ZMichelson thanks for accepting answer. I hope you got to this to work. If you put the above code in the same excel file's Module in the vba code editor (not your personal workbook), you should be able to use the actual function as a "regular" formula in excel or as a vba function. Note that the variables are classified as `Range`, so the inputs must be regions on the excel template.